# Exclude tag in flickr.photos.search

Tags: flickr

According to the docs for flickr.photos.search (https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html), the 'tags' variable is a comma-delimited list of tags. It also says, "You can exclude results that match a term by prepending it with a - character."

I keep trying to do something like "tags=cat,-catalog", but that doesn't give me any results. What's the proper format for excluding results in the REST query?

Comment: I tried this feature with the API Explorer, and I couldn't get it to work, either.  The Flickr API is prone to features that worked at one time, but don't any more.  You might try asking about this at the [Flickr API group](https://secure.flickr.com/groups/api/).

Comment: I second that. I tried to poke with the API method through https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search and you could clearly see that searching with a '-' either breakes the search or gives unwanted results.